# Merging and Averaging Data in R by ID and Date

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets that I would like to merge together in an unusual way. One dataset is my master set that contains an identifier and a datetime relevant to that `ID`. An `ID` can appear multiple times with different dates attached to it:

```
> head(Master_Data)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ID    Date               
  <chr> <dttm>             
1 a     2018-03-31 00:00:00
2 a     2018-02-28 00:00:00
3 b     2018-06-07 00:00:00
4 c     2018-01-31 00:00:00
5 b     2018-02-09 00:00:00
```

The other dataset has the same `ID`, a different date and a score associated with that `ID` and date. IDs can also show up multiple times in this dataset as well with different dates and scores:

```
> head(Score_Data)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ID    Date                   Score
  <chr> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1 a     2018-01-19 00:00:00     3
2 a     2018-01-01 00:00:00     5
3 a     2018-03-05 00:00:00     7
4 b     2018-01-31 00:00:00     1
5 b     2018-08-09 00:00:00     5
6 c     2018-01-17 00:00:00    10
```

What I would like to do is add an additional column to `Master_Data` that gives a mean of the score for that `ID` in the `Score_Data` df. The tricky part is that for each row in `Master_Data`, I only want to include scores in the average if the date variable in `Score_Data` is earlier than the date variable for a given row in `Master_Data`

Example:

For row 1 in `Master_Data`, I would want the new column to return a value of (3+5+7)/3 = 5. However, for row 2 I would only want to see (3+5)/2 = 4 since row 3 in `Score_Data` has a date after 2/28

Thoughts on what would be the best approach here to get this new column in `Master_Data`?

Comment: I think you need a non equi join

Comment: If you can provide a sample of both dataframes via `dput` and also write exactly what the output would look like for those two sample dataframes, someone can provide you a demonstration of one of the `joins` to make this happen. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution would work for smaller data sets, but as the size of the data grows you'll start to notice performance issues.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

master_data <- data.frame(
  ID = c('a','a','b','c','b'),
  Date = c('2018-03-31 00:00:00',
           '2018-02-28 00:00:00',
           '2018-06-07 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-31 00:00:00',
           '2018-02-09 00:00:00'))

master_data$Date <- ymd_hms(master_data$Date)

Score_Data <- data.frame(
  ID = c('a','a','a','b','b','c'),
  Date = c('2018-01-19 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-01 00:00:00',
           '2018-03-05 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-31 00:00:00',
           '2018-08-09 00:00:00',
           '2018-01-17 00:00:00'),
  Score = c(3,5,7,1,5,10))
Score_Data$Date <- ymd_hms(Score_Data$Date)

output <- apply(master_data, 1, function(x){

  value <- Score_Data %>%
    filter(ID == x[['ID']]) %>%
    filter(Date < x[['Date']]) %>%
    summarise(Val = mean(Score))

})

master_data$Output <- unlist(output)
```